# Display text after last occurrence of certain character (file-name)

Tags: vb.net

Ok so this time I'm using `VB.NET`. Still does'nt get VB as much as C#, but anycase.
What I have to do is display the last part of... lets say: `C:\Program Files\Data\12345.doc`.
All I want to see is `12345.doc`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a filename, so use [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx):

```
Dim fileName = Path.GetFileName("C:\Program Files\Data\12345.doc")
```

Comment: I have this:For Each attach As KeyValue In attachments
                isDoc = attach.GetDisplay
                isDocContains.Add(isDoc)
                lstAttachements.Items.Add(attach.GetDisplay)
                listlinkDocStore.Add(attach.GetID)
            Next

Comment: and the GetDisplay retrieves the whole path. I can not change that.

Comment: I don't understand. Then use `Path.GetFileName(attach.GetDisplay)` if you want just the file name instead of the full path.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
dim xStr="C:\Program Files\Data\12345.doc"
dim xResult=xstr.substring(xStr.lastIndexof("\"))
```

or May be like this,

```
dim xFilePath as New System.IO.FileInfo("C:\Program Files\Data\12345.doc")
 dim xFileName=xFilePath.Name
```

Comment: funny thing is that there is no Path.GetFileName function. I could just leave the full path in the listbox but that makes it look ugly.

Comment: Sorry guys this is not going to work for me. but I can see the logic. When I double click it opens that path... so It just needs to stay that way. thank you.

Comment: @Bebbie7 you need to open the path or you just need to get the file name.?

Comment: It should display the document on which I double clicked which is in a list box. but just to make it more pretty I didnt want to display the whole path and just display the file name. the "12345.doc".

Comment: @Bebbie7 So you need to open '12345.doc' when user double clicks on it through a list box right.?

Comment: @Bebbie7: Why are you commenting here that ther's no `Path.GetFileName`? The `Path` class (i linked) is in `System.IO`, so you either need to import that namespace or reference it fully: `System.IO.Path.GetFileName`. It is available since .NET 1.1.

Comment: There is no function for me like that. If there was I would have used id gradually but after importing it still does not allow me to use that. just gives me a handful of errors.

Comment: yes rajaprabhu thats it:). but no need to strain yourselves any more, I checked in the items and everyone seems happy with it the way it is.